# Matlab crashes after running a long for loop

Tags: matlab, plot

I am running this simple code where I compute some values into a formula and it generates new values into a vector. The problem is that it runs for about 5 minutes and then crashes. I would reduce the number of iteration but this is for an assignment and I need to plot all the results . Any suggestions?

I've tried preallocating memory but it did not help

```
clc
clear

G = 6.67*10^-11; % N*m^2*kg^-2
r = 6378*1000; % m
R = 100000*1000; % m
M = 5.97*10^24; % kg
d = R-r; %m


a = zeros(1,d);
for i = 1: d
a(i) = G*(M/i^2);
end
plot(d,a);
```

Comment: The problem that you are having is due to the plotting part. You run out of graphics memory

Answer (score 2):

Obviously you are studying the gravitational law.

Problem 1: Your variable `d` is scalar, you plot it against a vector `a` of length d = 93622. What you want is to plot `a` as a function of the values `1:d`. This fails because of memory limitations.

Problem 2: The gravitational force tends to 0 very fast because of the term 1/(r^2). You try to see all effects by plotting the function in steps of 1 meter which is a too fine discretization on astronomical scale. If you discretize at 1000 m = 1 km resolution MATLAB will give you a plot:

```
i = 1:1000:d;
a = G*(M./(i.^2));
plot(i,a);
```

However you do not recognize much on this scale, the function is practically 0 very soon. So either split the range of your plot to the range near earth, and a second range in outer space. Or plot the log of the force so you can see the variation over several orders of magnitude.

Efficiency consideration: You should use vectorization instead of `for`-loops where possible and understandable, this is idiomatic MATLAB, shorter and usually faster. You will need the dot-operator for componentwise division and power operations as above.